# How to disable silent installation in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield, installscript

Is there anyway to disable silent mode?

I want the installer to display the window even if I run Setup.exe with the -S option , I didn't find that option in the installScript project , i use installshield2021.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the InstallShield installation panel:
navigate towards Organization.
Then media
Under the media tab, there will be Setup.exe, entry
Right click and select properties.
In properties, go to command line
In this command line remove the -S option
This will do it.